# How to let an image define the layout's with in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-inflate, android-adapterview

I want an image to define the layout's bounds and need all other elemets to oriente themselfes to it.

[image: Screenshot]

My problem here is that i want the text to wrap, when it reaches the images end. Any idea how to solve this via layout xml or do I have to implement that via code?

My current layout looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/KHFGreen"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/five"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore. "
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: use matchparent for ur imageview and android:ellipsize="end" for text

Comment: Thanks for you answer but this doesn't change anything unfortunately :/

Comment: i can see that u want only border to ur layout then r u using image for the same?

Comment: Yeah, this layout will be inflated in a ListViewAdapter. I want an image with a green border around it and a text on top of that image. But the text should wrap when it reaches the image's end...

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible using only xml layouts. I think you'll need to tackle this programmatically.

Comment: Lets discuss -->http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add below logic in oncreate method.

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        textView.getLayoutParams().width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

When I removed android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" and tried I got what u asked
and I am not able to add android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" also, "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'nestedScrollingEnabled' in package 'android'"

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your effort but this is unfortunately also not what I need. As my screenshots provides a need a TextView that is not wider than the image and wraps where the image ends. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi einRobby, It can be done programmatically than doing in xml.

Comment: Yeah, when doing it programmatically it works. Thanks for your help guys. I have been developing for Windows (Phone) 8 until yet and am very spoiled by the designtools there :)